# Perl remove white space - copy file to new name

Tags: perl

I have download these file with spaces in the names. 
I want to replace the spaces with underbars - ultimately i want to change the name of the files - to get rid of the spaces and have names without spaces.  I am going to use File::Copy to institue changes in the file names but for now i want to keep old file names so I can sopy contents of file to new name.

```
$ ls  | perl -nle 'print if /\w\s.[jpg|png|pdf]/'
ls  | perl -nle 'print if /\w\s.[jpg|png|pdf]/' 
Effective awk Programming, 3rd Edition.pdf
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (15).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (19).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (30).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (4).jpg
sed &amp; awk, 2nd Edition.pdf
```

I use this code - but it has many difficulties and causes much consternation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict
opendir my $dir, "/cygdrive/c/Users/walt/Desktop" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;

foreach my $desktop_item (@files) {
    if ($desktop_item =~ /\w\s.[jpg|png|pdf]/) {
    my $underbar = $desktop_item =~ s/ /_/g;

    print "$desktop_item\n" ;
    print "$underbar\n" ;
    }
}
```

what I am trying to achieve is output like this - where you see we have original file name with spaces and then much newer file name with underbar (i like it much better for names with no spaces! )  :

```
Effective_awk_Programming,_3rd_Edition.pdf
Effective awk Programming, 3rd Edition.pdf
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(15).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (15).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(19).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (19).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(30).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (30).jpg
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(4).jpg
Fashion Photography by Edward Steichen in the 1920s and 1930s (4).jpg
sed_&amp;_awk,_2nd_Edition.pdf
sed &amp; awk, 2nd Edition.pdf
```

Ultimately I am going to goal cp old file to new file. howevers
this is the output that i get L:

```
./rename_jpg.pl
Effective_awk_Programming,_3rd_Edition.pdf
4
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(15).jpg
10
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(19).jpg
10
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(30).jpg
10
Fashion_Photography_by_Edward_Steichen_in_the_1920s_and_1930s_(4).jpg
10
sed_&amp;_awk,_2nd_Edition.pdf
4
```

the numbers are much confusing in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line doesn't assing the new name to $undebar:

```
my $underbar = $desktop_item =~ s/ /_/g;
```

The substitution in scalar context returns the number of substitutions. See [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)

> Searches a string for a pattern, and if found, replaces that pattern with the replacement text and returns the number of substitutions made.

The common idiom is to do the assignment first, then the substitution:

```
(my $underbar = $desktop_item) =~ s/ /_/g;
```

Or, since 5.14, you can use the `/r` modifier:

```
my $underbar = $desktop_item =~ s/ /_/gr;
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line => `my $underbar = $desktop_item =~ s/ /_/g;`
$underbar stores number of regular expression matches (space in your case) in given string.

Comment: foreach my $desktop_item (@files) {
    if ($desktop_item =~ /\w\s.[jpg|png|pdf]/) {
       print "$desktop_item\n" ; $desktop_item =~ s/ /_/g;                            print "$desktop_item\n" ;

    }
}